# MySql - concat expression keeps appending the same value

Tags: mysql

I am novice to mysql.

I am trying to write a query for below -

`Each PROJECT document will include the following data about each PROJECT object (document): PNAME, PNUMBER, DNAME (for the controlling DEPARTMENT), and a collection of the workers (EMPLOYEES) who work on the project. This will be nested within the PROJECT object (document) and will include for each worker: EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, HOURS.`

This is the query i wrote but it keeps appending the same value in Employees column.

```
SELECT Project.Pname, Project.Pnumber, Department.Dname,
(SELECT CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(Employee.Fname, Employee.Lname, Works_on.Hours),']') AS 'JSON' FROM Works_on 
JOIN Employee ON Employee.Ssn = Works_on.Essn WHERE Project.Pnumber=Works_on.Pno) AS Employees FROM Project JOIN Department 
ON Department.Dnumber=Project.Dnum WHERE Department.Dnumber = Project.Dnum;
```

This is the output.

[image]

As we can see, the `json` data in the `Employees` column contains the repeated values & keeps appending.

my schema looks like this -

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**is the query correct ? is the child query correct ? Kindly guide.**

my create query -

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEPARTMENT (DNAME varchar(20) NOT NULL, DNUMBER int(10) NOT NULL, MGR_SSN varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, MGR_START_DATE varchar(20) NOT NULL);"

"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EMPLOYEE (FNAME text NOT NULL, MINIT text, LNAME text NOT NULL, SSN varchar(9) NOT NULL, BDATE text NOT NULL, ADDRESS varchar(200) NOT NULL, SEX text NOT NULL, SALARY int(20) NOT NULL, SUPER_SSN int(9) DEFAULT NULL, DNO int(5) DEFAULT NULL);"

"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PROJECT (PNAME text NOT NULL, PNUMBER int(10) NOT NULL, PLOCATION text NOT NULL, DNUM int(10) DEFAULT NULL);"

"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WORKS_ON (ESSN varchar(20) NOT NULL, PNO int(10) NOT NULL, HOURS float DEFAULT NULL);"
```

`department data`

```
'Administration', 4, '987654321', '01-JAN-1985'
```

`project data`

```
'ProductX', 1, 'Bellaire', 5
```

`works on data`

```
'123456789', 1, 32.5
'123456789', 2, 7.5
```

`employee data`

```
'James', 'E', 'Borg', '888665555', '10-NOV-1927', '450 Stone,Houston,TX', 'M', 55000, null, 1
'Franklin', 'T', 'Wong', '333445555', '08-DEC-1945', '638 Voss,Houston,TX', 'M', 40000, '888665555', 5
```

`insert query`
`INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT (DNAME, DNUMBER, MGR_SSN, MGR_START_DATE) VALUES ('Networking', 3, '110110110', '15-MAY-2009' );`

**can anyone help me to resolve this.**

Thanks,

Jay

Comment: As I already told you in your other question: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. That applies to all questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem:
".... it keeps appending the same value in Employees column"

What happens:
Where does the column Employees get it values from?
Is is the query:

```
SELECT 
   CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(Employee.Fname, Employee.Lname, Works_on.Hours),']') AS 'JSON' 
FROM Works_on 
JOIN Employee ON Employee.Ssn = Works_on.Essn 
WHERE Project.Pnumber=Works_on.Pno
```

And, if this query produces the same EmployeeName multiple times, then you would indeed see this problem.

If we change the query and add the word `DISTINCT` :

```
SELECT 
   CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Employee.Fname, Employee.Lname, Works_on.Hours),']') AS 'JSON' 
FROM Works_on 
JOIN Employee ON Employee.Ssn = Works_on.Essn 
WHERE Project.Pnumber=Works_on.Pno
```

your problem will be solved.